# gnuplot sample value curve with correct time scaling

Tags: gnuplot, scale, axis, sample

I have a pure 1D list of any sample values and want to plot the time curve of them.
How do I scale the x axis to secs, knowing the time interval and total duration?
I have

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"
set trange [0 : 3.5]
plot 'some.dat' using ??? with lines
```

What is missing?
How are the parameters for using?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I got your question right. Assuming you have a single column in your data file and two samples are taken at a constant time difference you can plot it with:

```
# time interval
dt = 0.1
# time range in seconds
set xrange [0:10]
plot 'some.dat' using ($0 * dt):1 with lines
```

`$0` is the row number which is then scaled by the time interval `dt`. There is no need to use `set xdata time` if you want to display only seconds.